# how do i remove client_secret when calling auth_code.get_token method in a custom omniauth oauth2 based strategy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, omniauth

I created a custom oauth2 omniauth strategy loosely based on the template here https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2.  It works well until I get to the 3rd leg where I am exchanging the access code for an access token.

My strategy subclasses the omniauth oauth2 strategy, and therefore uses its `build_access_token` method (see https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb) to execute the exchange.  The `build_access_token` method in turn calls `client.auth_code.get_token`, which lives in the "oauth2" gem (see https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb).  The `get_token` method adds `client_secret` as a param to the request.  How do I remove `client_secret` from the request - or override it?

I have a good reason for doing so, and looking for guidance on how to accomplish it from within my custom strategy.  Tx